# Android Webview equivalent in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have text with some HTML tags in it.

Example : `<I> I Play Football and Cricket </I>`

Now when i try to display this text in Textblock it displays with `Italics tag <I>` as well.

The data is present in the XML file and i am working on `Windows Phone 8 application.`

In Android we use Webview, but what do i need to use here ?

**EDIT**

I have tried using TextBlock with inlines:

```
Italic itlText = new Italic();
itlText.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "This is some example text in italics" });
Inilinetext.Inlines.Add(itlText);
```

It works good But issue here is suppose i have a text like below.

```
"This is text in <I>Italics</I> here"
```

Now it display entire text in italics.

Comment: Have you tried using WebBrowser control?

Comment: @TutanComeOn No i havent tried it, how to use that?

Comment: Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much content you want to display. If you will show large amount of HTML text, use `WebBrowser` control for that.
In case you only have a couple of tags i, em, b or strong, then you can actually use `TextBlock`, but you would have to do the parsing yourself then in order to convert the HTML to the suitable XAML components.

You also have to ask yourself how many such controls you need to display on a single page. If the answer is *a few*, use the `WebBrowser` then. If you need to display lots of them, say you have a chat or a feed, then the second route would be better.

EDIT:
Use the following code:

```
Inilinetext.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "This is text in " });
Inilinetext.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Italics", FontStyle = FontStyle.Italic });
Inilinetext.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = " here" });
```

I told you you have to *parse* the original string to see which parts are italic and which are not.

Comment: I have couple of tags like I,b but in that case how i use a text block ? because what i saw is the text which i am getting from XML is already with <i> tag, but while its displaying i just need to display the text within in ITalics

Comment: You need to parse that HTML code and turn it into inline `Run` elements which you add to the `Inlines` property of your `TextBlock`. That is what I meant by parsing. You don't set the `Text` property when you want to use styling.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.